# How to create dummy user?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, permissions, user-management

I want to create user with least privileges. Without home, without rights, without shell. How to do that?
When I call useradd it creates user with home

Comment: Did you even look at the manual for `useradd`?

Comment: I like the question. Even if some assume the problem so simple that a `man useradd` would suffice, I can imagine that there is more involved here and actually implicitly asked for. I cannot understand the downvote.

Comment: `man useradd 2>&1 | egrep -i 'dummy|rights' | wc -l` gives `0`, so this is a good question!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the man page, this command will create a user with no home directory, and no shell.

```
 useradd -M -s /bin/false <desired username>
```